# is it necessary to use serialVersionUID in HttpServlet when sending email by the server when firing event

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm trying to send email when creating a specific type of requests in app engine 
so I'm using `TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("path/to/httpServlet/class")` to start the the servlet , but in the servlet class i get the warning **The serializable class sendEmail does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long**. so is it necessary to define this serialVersionUID ?

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is necessary depends on the serializable class, and how it is going to be used.

If instances of the class isn't actually going to be serialized at all, then it makes absolutely no difference.  The `serialVersionUID` is only used when objects are serialized and deserialized.

The utility of the `serialVersionUID` field arises when the agents doing the serialization and deserialization could *potentially* be using different versions of the class OR could be running on different Java platforms.  Here's what [Object Serialization Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) says:

> The stream-unique identifier is a 64-bit hash of the class name, interface class names, methods, and fields. The value must be declared in all versions of a class except the first. It may be declared in the original class but is not required. The value is fixed for all compatible classes. If the SUID is not declared for a class, the value defaults to the hash for that class. The `serialVersionUID` for dynamic proxy classes and `enum` types always have the value `0L`. Array classes cannot declare an explicit `serialVersionUID`, so they always have the default computed value, but the requirement for matching `serialVersionUID` values is waived for array classes.
>
> Note - It is strongly recommended that all serializable classes explicitly declare `serialVersionUID` values, since the default `serialVersionUID` computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected `serialVersionUID` conflicts during deserialization, causing deserialization to fail.

Summarizing that:

- If you don't declare a `serialVersionUID`, you could get unwarranted exceptions caused by conflicts that are not real.  (For example, if you just changed a method *name* without altering the representational semantics of the class.)
- But if you do declare a `serialVersionUID`, and you do make an incompatible change to a class, then you ought to change the value of the `serialVersionUID` ... unless you are going to use one of the other mechanisms that object serialization provides for converting "on the fly".

Note that SUIDs are trying to provide a practical solution<sup>1</sup> to the [schema evolution problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_evolution).  It is a really difficult problem.

---

<sup>1 - It is not sound from the type-theoretic perspective.  There are many ways to violate type abstraction.   However the SUID mechanism is emminently practical, and is as good as is possible given the nature of the Java programming language, the need for efficiency, etcetera.</sup>

Comment: thanks for the answer
as i could get from the post i think i don't need to use the serialVersionUID cause I'm not exchanging objects of the class to be serialized and deserialized

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple hours ago, I had this extremely stupid behavior and was about to rant here on stackoverflow with lots of f-bombs, but luckily the issue was fixed with adding this serialVersionUID even though there is no serialization involve at all.

So I was asked to embed some images from a local folder that is outside of the project for demoing purposes. After finding out that I cannot do that directly. I had to call the servlet to serve the image for me. Fortunately, we already have a servlet to serve the image so I don't have to create or configure anything extra:

```
<img src="DownloadServlet?filePath=C:/path/to/myfile.png">
```

The problem is DownloadServlet's service() is never invoked. So I test out other servlets that are set up exactly in the web.xml that are in the same package as DownloadServlet. I was getting really pissed off that all of them worked except for the one I wanted. What sucks is that the only difference between this servlet and other servlets was this one is missing the serialVersionID. I really wanted to start cursing on stackoverflow but figured nobody would help me if I did. I doubt anything would be able to help anyway if they want to. There was nothing else I could do really other than adding it and try again, so:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

And boom, it worked. This is the stupidest shit I have ever seen in my 3 years of programming. This beat all the shit that is Javascript and CSS.